# Unable to install Cassandra cluster from Lifecycle Manager

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to install a cassandra cluster using Lifecycle Manager, but I have this error :

> Meld execution failed: Failure to install Java: Could not determine if java installation is necessary. Java must either be installed as a pre-requisite, or it must be configured to to be installed via the java-setup section of a config-profile: Java must either be installed as a pre-requisite, or it must be configured to to be installed via the java-setup section of a config-profile

The problem here is I have already Java installed on the machine:

`echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_8u242b08`

Can you please give me some ideas about that problem ? Where should I look first ?

Comment: what version of OpsCenter

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java already installed, just configure OpsCenter to not install it [as described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/opsc/LCM/opscLCMmanageJavaInstalls.html).  Go to "Config profiles", select profile to use, find "Java Setup" section, and uncheck the "manage-java" checkbox.

Comment: It is the case but I still have the problem.